# Increment all numbers in a file

Tags: python, regex, bash, scripting

I have a file which looks like:

```
(890 1782 0)
(8 9 56)(5 28 987)
```

And I want to increment every number by one:

```
(891 1783 1)
(9 10 57)(6 29 988)
```

I am sure there must be a simple way of doing this, but I can't figure it out. Happy with any language (bash/awk/perl/python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find all numbers by using `\d+` regular expression, use [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) and pass a function to as a `repl` argument. For modifying a file in place, you can use [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html):

```
import fileinput
import re

pattern = re.compile('\d+')
for line in fileinput.input('input.txt', inplace=True):
    if line:
        print pattern.sub(lambda m: str(int(m.group(0)) + 1), line)
```

Example (using a string instead of a file):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "(891 1783 1)"
>>> pattern = re.compile('\d+')
>>> pattern.sub(lambda m: str(int(m.group(0)) + 1), s)
'(892 1784 2)'
```

Comment: This adds an extra newline for every line, though.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
numbers=$(egrep -o "[0-9]+" input.txt | xargs printf "%d + 1\n"  | bc)
printf "$(cat input.txt  | sed -r 's/[0-9]+/%d/g')\n" $numbers
```